# Cannot update the value in Text input

Tags: react-native, textinput

I cannot update the existing value in text input.

```
<TextField
              label='Email Id'
              //placeholder={value_email}
              onChangeText={(email) => this.setState({ email })}
              value={value_email}
            />
```

here value_email is

```
const value_email = this.state.userInfo.email;
```

Thanks.

Comment: can you try this ? onChangeText = {(email) =>this.setState(prevState => {
  let jasper = Object.assign({}, prevState.userInfo);  
  jasper.email = email
  return { jasper };                               
}) }

Comment: `TextField` is not any built in component in React native. share your custom implementation or from where you imported.

Comment: import { TextField } from 'react-native-materialui-textfield';

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this.setState({ email }` Sets the email to state object (this.state.email) but you are reading it from `state.userInfo`.

If you are setting it to state variable you need to change to 
`const value_email = this.state.email;`

Answer (score 0):

You are setting the state wrog , if you want to store inside an object userInfo state , try this :

```
  <TextInput
              label='Email Id'
               style={{ height: 40, borderColor: 'gray', borderWidth: 1 }}
              //placeholder={value_email}
             onChangeText = {(email) =>this.setState(prevState => { let userInfo = Object.assign({}, prevState.userInfo); userInfo.email = email 
            return { userInfo }; }) } 
              value={this.state.userInfo.email}
            />
```

Now you can get the value as `const value_email = this.state.userInfo.email;`

Comment: can you share an expo link? ill make it work for you

Comment: hey can you try this? https://snack.expo.io/ryoBNP9ir . 

in this approach , you will set the value of email inside the userinfo object rather than creating a new variable called email in state.